# Как с помощью скрипта Perl загрузить dll и вызвать из нее функцию?

Tags: perl

Как с помощью скрипта Perl загрузить dll и вызвать из нее функцию? Как должна быть загружена dll динамически или статистически (зарегистрирована в ОС)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это достаточно просто делается с помощью [Win32::API](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ACALPINI/Win32-API-0.20/API.html)

```
  use Win32::API;
  $function = new Win32::API(
      $library, $functionname, \@argumenttypes, $returntype,
  );
  $return = $function->Call(@arguments);
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
Можно пример? Хочу видеть какие данные должны иметь переменные...

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью `rundll32`

```
`rundll.exe ....`
```

[Документация](http://www.jaans.info/opisanie-protsessa-rundll32exe)